# which include file has contain "wxEVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED" macro?

Tags: erlang, wxwidgets

erlang 24.3.3 is used.

From the 24.3.3 document, the `wx` version is 2.1.3.
I have find 2.1.3's `wx.hrl` and it doesn't contain the `wxEVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED` and `wxEVT_WEBVIEW_ERROR`.
But in the doc, it says

> Many of the methods in wxWebView are asynchronous, i.e. they return
> immediately and perform their work in the background. This includes
> functions such as loadURL/2 and reload/2. To receive notification of
> the progress and completion of these functions you need to handle the
> events that are provided. Specifically wxEVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED notifies
> when the page or a sub-frame has finished loading and
> wxEVT_WEBVIEW_ERROR notifies that an error has occurred.

My code is as follows:

```
Ad = wxWebView:new(Frame,?wxID_ANY,[{size,{1000,1000}}]),
lager:debug("_ad_1082:\t~p",[Ad]),
ok = wxWebView:loadURL(Ad,"http://www.baidu.com"),
wxFrame:connect(Ad, ?wxEVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED,[{callback,fun chair_launch_frame:update_webview/2},
                               {userData,{?CONST_FRAME_MAIN_AD_PRODUCER,Frame}}]),
wxFrame:connect(Ad, ?wxEVT_WEBVIEW_ERROR,[{callback,fun chair_launch_frame:update_webview/2},
                                {userData,{?CONST_FRAME_MAIN_AD_PRODUCER,Frame}}]),
```

The compiler give error messsage `undefined macro 'wxEVT_WEBVIEW_LOADED'`

Comment: "Enable wxUSE_WEBVIEW_EDGE in setup.h" https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_web_view.html

Comment: Although I use webkit, "docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_web_view.html" have the  clue, the problem is cause the webkit doesn't support http and unsecured https.